# MBP battery won't charge

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I have a MacBook Pro Early 2011 model A1278 which wasn't turning on, then I bought a new battery and it ran just fine. But the charger isn't charging it up (the charger is also fine, I tested in another MBP). I tried to reset SMC, NVRAM and cleaned the charging port, but nothing happened. 
Now the battery just died (0%) and I don't know what to do, since I can't charge it up. Is there anything I can do to make it work?

Thanks in advance,
Luiz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you didn't fix the original problem which was why your MBP wasn't turning on in the first place - your battery wasn't charging so you had a dead battery.

You have already verified that...

- the battery is good (it's new)
- the charger is good as it works on another Mac
- the logic board is good because when the battery has juice, it works.

Now, it seems that since the battery has gone to 0% and the charger is plugged in, your MBP is dead, correct?

**That means you Mag Safe DC In board** is most likely shot.

[image: MagSafe Board MBP 2011]

This is fairly simple to fix (I am assuming you changed your own battery). [iFixit.com](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Early+2011+MagSafe+DC-In+Board+Replacement/5152) has an excellent tutorial on how to replace this component.  The good news is that this component is fairly inexpensive ($11 on [Amazon](http://radnex.us/mbp-2011-dc-in-board)).

Comment: Thank you!! I actually have another MBP (mid 2009) that is working. It's also A1278. So, assuming this is the problem, changing the Mag Safe DC In board between the two MBP would make my newest (early 2011) work?

Comment: It should.  The worst that can happen is I am wrong and it's not the component - the upside is you would have narrowed it to the logic board, but I am confident that the logic board is not the problem.